# How to Check that String is alphanumeric in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check the entered String is alphanumeric or not.I tried some regular expressions i.e.,

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
 ^[A-Za-z0-9]*$
 ^[\pL\pN]+$
```

But all these will work if the String contains only numeric or contains only alphabets or alphanumeric. But I need to check the String should be AlphaNumeric and Starts with a digit only. Please help me out.

Comment: You can do a try-catch and parse your value to an int or double. If it fails and throws an exception you know it's not a numeric value.

Comment: It appears you want to add the requirement that it start with a digit. So I would add a digit to the start of your regex.  What did you try to meet this requirement and what problem are you having?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should post some examples of input and expected results with explanation why such results are expected (why they are correct/incorrect)?

Comment: Note: AlphaNumeric usually means containing any combination of letters or digits and can be only letters or digits.

Comment: IMO an upvote isn't warranted on a regex question like this since (a) exact examples are easily searchable, and (b) the OP clearly hasn't tried very hard to find an answer. While a downvote might be too much, there is little redeeming value given the ambiguous wording and lack of followup.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ok.But in my case I need to allow a String contains both letters and digits only.

Comment: @Ganesh Those aren't the complete requirements. Pshemo asked for examples, which are required since your description is, at best, subject to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.matches("[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"); 
// ensures you have atleast 1 number, 1 alphabet and starts with a number/digit
```

Comment: This one works fine.I need to take the String with , as separator like this '2012IND00013,2012IND0014'.Then how to change this reg exp.Please suggest.

Comment: @Ganesh Split on commas and test each one, particularly if there are an arbitrary number of CSVs. And take some time to learn regexes, espeically when they're this simple.

Comment: @Ganesh - I would take dave's advice :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Need to check without splitting the String

Comment: @Ganesh ... So use the same expression twice, with a comma in the middle, and watch out for greediness. But a requirement to check without splitting doesn't seem reasonable. Also, not updating the question to be clearer is irresponsible--you were asked to do so, and you saw the confusion your question caused.

Comment: Previous I am checking the numeric String with commas with ** [0-9]+(,[0-9]+)* ** reg exp.Now I need to do the same with alphanumeric String

Comment: @Ganesh - "Need to check without splitting the String". Why exactly?. Splitting the String will make it easier to check. You could also use the current REGEX with comma, but I somehow don't like that approach.

Answer (score 0):

So you want at least one letter after the first digit. Right?

Then use

```
^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: Not sure it states a letter must appear after a digit.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Where else would it appear?

Comment: Where does the OP state it has to appear anywhere?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: They're in the first sentence after the code sample

Comment: @TimPietzcker that sentence is talking about regex the OP doesn't want.  He then says `But I need to check`